# what is the best query to find missing index in sql server 2008r2 and how to resolve missing index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, performance, performance-tuning

identify missing index and solve indexing problem

Comment: This is almost certainly going to get closed as a opinion question. But my vote is sp_BlitzIndex here: https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

Comment: I will add a +1 to @SqlZim's answer of Brent Ozar.

Comment: i just got sp_BlitzIndex thank you @SqlZim

Comment: i will follow you@ Shaulinator

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sp_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) to find the high-value missing indexes, `@mode=3` will specifically only show the high-value missing indexes. Target the ones with an "Estimated benefit per day" that are greater than 5,000,000. See if your workload improves after making the changes.

Disclosure: I work at Brent Ozar Unlimited.

Comment: i am so happy you guys are helping me to grow up as a SQL DBA ,thank you @Tara Kizer

Answer (score 2):

Another compliment to @Tara's answer is to use [Microsoft's Tigertoolbox](https://github.com/Microsoft/tigertoolbox) (has a lot of scripts which are actively maintained by the CSS engineers) - [`view_IndexCreation.sql`](https://github.com/Microsoft/tigertoolbox/blob/master/Index-Creation/view_IndexCreation.sql)

> Purpose: Looks for relevant missing indexes in SQL Server. Results are relevant if one or more business cycles have been executed.
>
> In the output, you will find the following information:
>
> - Missing indexes with the highest user impact. The higher the score, higher is the anticipated improvement for user queries.
> - Possibly redundant indexes in above list, whcih provides an opportunity to do some index consolidation.
> - Index creation scripts.